# Prove that $2^p+p^2$ is prime for $p=3$ only

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I do know that all prime numbers larger than $3$ can be expressed as $3k + 1$ and or $3k + 2$. Plugging those in I still see no solution.

EDIT: $p$ can only be a prime number.

Comment: $p$ is a prime right? Otherwise I think both $0$ and $1$ work too...

Comment: Well, basically $2^p\equiv 2 \pmod 3$ and $p^2\equiv 1$ so ...

Comment: @Dair, I guess that depends on how prime you feel $1$ is...

Comment: @lulu Not true.  $2^4=16\equiv1\pmod 3$...

Comment: @lulu thanks, i was writing it as $2^p\equiv1$

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII I bet p is prime

Comment: @NickPeterson  $4$ is not a prime.  Granted you have to treat $p=2$ as a separate case.

Comment: @EzWin: Yes, I just realized.  :)

Comment: @lulu OP hadn't said $p$ was prime yet. :-)  Perfectly fair.

Comment: Note:  you don't need $p$ to be a prime, just odd and prime to $3$.

Comment: @lulu no need for the odd requirement,if $p$ is even then $2^p+p^2$ is even

Comment: @kingW3   Good point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether $p\equiv 1\pmod 3$ or $p\equiv 2\pmod 3$, either way $p^2\equiv 1\pmod 3$

Since $p$ must be odd, $2^p\equiv 2\pmod 3$

Adding them together gets you a number that is divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 3):

So you know that all primes larger than 3 are of the form $3k + 1$ or $3k + 2$.

Do you know which of those forms $2^p$ is? Obviously $2 = 3 \times 0 + 2$. Then $4 = 3 \times 1 + 1$, $8 = 3 \times 2 + 2$, $16 = 3 \times 5 + 1$, $32 = 3 \times 10 + 2$, etc. In short, $2^n \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ if $n$ is odd, so if $p$ is a prime number greater than 2, it's odd, and consequently $2^p \equiv 2 \pmod 3$. Let's say $2^p = 3m + 2$ for later reference.

Now let's review what happens with the squares of primes. Suppose $p = 3k + 2$. Then $p^2 = (3k + 2)^2 = 9k^2 + 12k + 4 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

And so $2^p + p^2 = (3m + 2) + (9k^2 + 12k + 4) = 9k^2 + 12k + 3m + 6$, and, just in case it's not obvious enough: $$\frac{9k^2 + 12k + 3m + 6}{3} = 3k^2 + 4k + m + 2.$$

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* If $p$ is odd, then $2^p+p^2 \equiv -1+p^2 =(p-1)(p+1) \bmod 3$.

Answer (score 2):

From [Fermat's little theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatsLittleTheorem.html), it follows that $2^p \equiv 2 \pmod p$. Then $2^p + p^2 \equiv 2 \pmod p$... oops, that doesn't help, never mind.

Oh, wait a minute: since $2 = 3 - 1$, then $p^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ by Fermat's little theorem. That means $p^2$ is of the form $3k + 1$.

So as long as $2^p \not \equiv 2 \pmod 3$, the number $2^p + p^2$ has a shot at being prime. However, since $2^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ but $2^3 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$, it follows that the powers of $2$ alternate $2, 1 \pmod n$ according to whether $n$ is odd or even. But since $p > 2$ is odd, it follows that $2^p \equiv 2 \pmod 3$. Therefore, with $p > 3$ odd, $2^p + p^2$ must be a multiple of $3$.

And the only prime multiples of $3$ are $3$ itself and $-3$. So it is only with $p = 3$ that we have $2^3 + 3^2 = 17$.

---

Just as an amusing aside: given $p = -3$, we have $$2^p + p^2 = \frac{73}{8}.$$